# Display part of mysql_fetch_assoc() different

Tags: php

On my website there is a menu at the top. This only works with 5 menu options, but sometimes there are more. This depends on what is fetched from the database. For 5 options or less, it can be displayed like this:

```
<ul>
    <li>First option</li>
    <li>Second option</li>
    <li>Third option</li>
    <li>Fourth option</li>
    <li>Fifth option</li>
</ul>
```

If there are more then 5 options, it should be displayed like this:

```
<ul>
    <li>First option</li>
    <li>Second option</li>
    <li>Third option</li>
    <li>Fourth option</li>
    <li>Misc.
        <ul>
            <li>Fifth option</li>
            <li>Sixth option</li>
            <li>Seventh option</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

This is the PHP Code, I have:

```
$result = //the query;
$numberOfRows = mysql_num_rows($result);
if ($numberOfRows > 5) {
    $i = 1;
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        while ($i < 5) {
            //the part I don't get
        }
    }
} else {
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo "<li>".$row['page']."</li>";
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to try following :

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result) && $i < 5) {
    //your logic
    $i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$result = //the query;
$MAX_NUMBER = 5;
$count = 0;
$totalRows = mysql_num_rows($result);
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $count++;
    if($totalRows > $MAX_NUMBER && $count == $MAX_NUMBER){echo "<li><ul>Misc.";}
    echo "<li>".$row['page']."</li>";
}
if($totalRows > $MAX_NUMBER){echo "</ul></li>";}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make it like this:

```
$numberOfRows = mysql_num_rows($result);

$i = 1;

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

if($i==5) {
       echo "<li>Misc.<ul><li>".$row['page']."</li>";

      $i++;
      continue;
    }
    echo "<li>".$row['page']."</li>";
    $i++;
}

echo "</ul></li>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually I'd dump everything into an array `$data[]` and process it. (Maintenance is easier when I write simple code blocks and stitch them together). Here's code snippet:-

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $data[] = $row;
}
```

Next, process `$data[]` while avoiding `while`.  IMHO, too many nested `while` loops is confusing, try using [foreach()](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

```
if (sizeof($data) <= 5) {
    // print simple <ul>
} else {
    // Step1: print 4 rows with foreach() 
    // Step2: print ".misc" + extra UL & LI tags
    // Step3: print 5th row onwards, foreach() again
    // Step4: closing UL & LI tags.
}
```